# Arduino Uno Wifi R2 Mesh Network

Tags: network, arduino-uno-wifi

I currently have a project that uses a few Xbee S1 modules to report temperature measurements to a computer. I'm thinking about reworking the project to use the newer Arduino Uno WiFi R2 boards.

Is there an existing library that will allow me to create a mesh network for a number of Wifi R2's (about 20+)? I know there's a [Mesh Library for the ESP8266](https://github.com/PhracturedBlue/ESP8266MQTTMesh) I'd be curious if I could either use this library or if one exits for the native board

Comment: why do you want to use Uno WiFi for this? two MCU? IMU? crypto chip? not compatible sensor libraries?

Comment: I was thinking about using the Uno WiFi for the simplicity of having most functionality on one board. I also want some level of security (like that provided by the crypto chip)

Comment: ok. don't buy 20. try one first

Comment: Fair point, I'll get 2-3 to verify 1st. I want to make sure the solution is able to do 20+ish

Comment: first test if it works with your sensors. it is ATMega4809. it has a different  architecture then the classic Uno 328p

Comment: It will, the sensors are run through an I2C ADC.

Comment: the crypto-chip and IMU are already on I2C. the Nina esp32 is wired to I2C too (not used yet). and there is no mesh support yet in WiFiNina firmware and library. why not use esp8266?